# Android Bluetooth search in service for available devices

Tags: java, android, background-process

I am trying to discover available blueetooth devices in background service. I am stuck at the part "startActivityForResult" as service is not an Activity. please help...

```
private void CheckBTState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
    // If it isn't request to turn it on
    // List paired devices
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    Log.d("check","4");
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
//        out.append("\nBluetooth is enabled...");

        // Starting the device discovery
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();
        Log.d("check","5");
      } else {

        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        Log.d("check","6");

  STUCK OVER HERE.... DON'T NO HOW TO CALL startActivityForResult IN SERVICE

 // ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      //  activity.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);


      }


}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you're using (Java, ...). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate BlueTooth before service started.

Just add to your Activity this code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == <needed value>) {


    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Need to run entire thing in background service. Not using activity. Need to scan for available bluetooth devices, and match them with one's already in my database.

Comment: BlueTooth adapter at your device should be turned on before you run backgroung service. Reason is too simple: user have to tap the button to turn BlueTooth On

Comment: Yup, my bluetooth adapter is on.. Now the issue is I have to get all the available devices in background service.....

Comment: In background service you can only check if bluetooth adapter is on. You cannot turn it on or send request to turn it on at background service :(

Comment: Sir, my bluetooth is switching on in service. All I need to do is search for available devices and iterate the list to match with previously saved list

Comment: @user5171632 Did you find a way to accomplish this? I am also looking to solve the same issue